# 3d plot of a function with a constraint in R

Tags: r

I would like to draw a 3D plot of the function `z=f(x,y)=x^2+y^2, y>x>0` [see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGCz1.png)
I know the way to do that without the constraint `y>x>0` which is easy. could you please help me.
My code for the version without the constraint

```
fxy <- function(x,y){
return(x^2+y^2)}
x <- seq(-100 ,100, by=5)
y <- seq(-100 ,100, by=5)
z <- outer(x, y, fxy)
persp(x, y, z,
  main="3D Plot of x2+y2",
  zlab = "Function",
  theta = 20, phi = 10,
  col = "blue")
```

Comment: Please show your attempt (i.e. the version without the constraint).

Comment: @Marcinthebox  I added my attempt for the version without the constraint. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this with the base `persp` function, but it's possible with `rgl`.

```
library(rgl)
fxy <- function(x,y){
  return(x^2+y^2)}
x <- seq(-100 ,100, by=5)
y <- seq(-100 ,100, by=5)
z <- outer(x, y, fxy)

# First, draw the full surface:
full <- surface3d(x, y, z,
                  col = "blue")
# Convert it to a mesh object:
m1 <- as.mesh3d(full)
# Clip to x > 0
m2 <- clipMesh3d(m1, "x", bound = 0, greater = TRUE)
# Clip to y > x
m3 <- clipMesh3d(m2, function(x,y,z) y-x, bound = 0, greater = TRUE)
# Plot it
plot3d(m3)
```

You can now rotate it to whatever orientation you like.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, After executing, for the line m2 it gives an error saying that Error in fn(arg) : could not find function "fn".

Comment: What versions of `rgl` and `R` are you using?  (Run `packageVersion("rgl")`, and `R.version.string` to see.)

Comment: rgl version ‘0.100.30’ and R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12).

Comment: Those are both pretty old.  If you can't update, you'll need to specify the functions differently:  `m2 <- clipMesh3d(m1, function(xyz) xyz[,1], bound = 0, greater = TRUE)` and `m3 <- clipMesh3d(m2, function(xyz) xyz[,2]-xyz[,1], bound = 0, greater = TRUE)`.  I forget what other bugs you'll run into; I recommend updating!

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I update R and rgl and it works.